# Cannot run php script to load images

Tags: php, image, kloxo

I use a php file to show pictures in a clean page. I add to all pics the url `site.xx/image.php?pic=/xx/xx.jpg`. It works well and show the images, but when I move my sites to vps with kloxo it stops working and the pics dont load in the php.

example:

file.php

```
    <?php

$notitle = ""; // Text to Display in No title present
$noimage = "No Image Supplied";    // Error message if no image url

if (file_exists('adbrite.html')) {
    $temfile = fopen('adbrite.html', 'r');
    $template = fread($temfile, filesize('adbrite.html'));
    if ($title) {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTURETITLE>", $title, $template);
    } else {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTURETITLE>", $notitle, $template);
    }
    if ($desc) {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTUREDESCRIPTION>", $desc, $template);
    }
    if ($pic) {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTURE>", "src=\"$pic\">", $template);
    } else {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTURE>", $noimage, $template);
    }
    if ($return) {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTURELINK>", "<a href=\"$return\">RETURN TO DICKISM</a>", $template);
    } else {
        $template = eregi_replace("<PICTURELINK>", "<a href=\"/\">RETURN TO DICKISM</a>", $template);
    }
    echo $template;
}
```

Comment: 1) don't use ereg functions. they're obsolete/deprecated. 2) have you done ANY debugging on this? You're basically saying "it works in case #1, but doesn't work in completely different case #2". How could **WE** possibly guess what the differences are?

Comment: Yes work in CPANEL, but this week i move my site to a kloxo vps. and the same script dont run!.

Comment: so yes. you've changed servers, operating system versions, PHP versions, library versions, blah blah blah... and yet think that this doesn't matter?

Comment: try using some PHP exception handling to find error.